# How to access command-line arguments from a Python script?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am writing code in Python that I should run with the command line and when I call the script i should give some arguments that I would use in the code. What can I use to achieve that?

To run the script it would be something like this:

```
python myscript.py s1 s2 s4
```

where `s1`, `s2` and `s4` would be the arguments that I would use in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick dirty way

```
import sys
s1, s2, s4 = sys.argv[1:4]
```

(`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script)

For more flexibility you can use the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module

Comment: @leo: If you prefer argparse than I prefer [Doug Hellman's tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/argparse/) on argparse.

Answer (score 4):

Check out: http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

Python has a built in argument parser.

Answer (score 1):

This is describe in the section entitled ["Argument Passing"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing) in the excellent [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
import sys
print "file name:", sys.argv[0]
for i in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    print "param:\t", i, sys.argv[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a FAQ. The `sys` module has the facilities to access interpreter details. And one of the attribute `sys.argv` is list of command line arguments passed to the `interpreter`.
So, when you access the `sys.argv` from a python program, which is executed by the interpreter, you will the program itself as the first argument and then rest of the arguments following it in the list starting from index 1.

```
$ cat 1.py 
import sys
print sys.argv
```

And when I execute it.

```
$python 1.py 0
['1.py', '0']
```